# Can some one identify this part from under a Renault Captur 1.4 dci 2018

Tags: engine, part-identification, renault

Does anyone know what this is
From under the engine of a 2018 Renault Captur 1.4 dci

[image]

[image: captur 1.4 dci]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have any further pictures of it (other side, better connector shot, etc)? Where exactly on the engine does it attach to? Any closeups of any numbers on the item? A little more context?

Comment: This should be the throttle but it is broken

Comment: https://goo.gl/images/rdK1Px

Comment: This Fell offafter driving over some thing, engine management light on and csr still drives.